# How to create folder in prinstream?

Tags: java

The code given below gets the absolute path of in the string absolutePath file post_tran.tbl and path of folder in filePath.
Now I want to create a new folder named test in the filepath which should contain final.tbl. Can you please suggest me?

```
String absolutePath = new File("post_tran.tbl").getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println("File path : " + absolutePath);

String filePath = absolutePath.substring(0,absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));


PrintStream out = new PrintStream(filePath+"_final.tbl");
//want to create a folder named test which should contain final.tbl
```

Comment: Create folder first and then use PrintStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Java.io.File class
The method .mkdirs() creates directories(folders) and .createNewFile() creates files.

Example Code:

```
try{
//make File object
File testfolder=new File("C:/test");
//create folder
testfolder.mkdirs();
//make another file object
File Finialfile=new File("C:/test/finial.tbl"); 
//create file
Finialfile.createNewFile();
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Note:
 These methods throw exceptions so you must either surround it with a try and catch(like I did) or you can make the method throw an exception.

Edit: how you can implement it in your program:

```
try{
//make File object
File testfolder=new File(filePath);
//create folder
testfolder.mkdirs();
//make another file object
File Finialfile=new File(testfolder,"/finial.tbl"); 
//create file
Finialfile.createNewFile();
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: how should I apply it to my example.I tried but it dont create any folder

Comment: Replace "C:/test" with filepath and "C:/test/finial.tbl" with filePath+"/finial.tbl"

Comment: "`new File(filePath+"/finial.tbl");`" - Don't do that. Use `new File(testFolder,"final.tbl");` instead.

Comment: Yes Hanno, I have changed that

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to operate on the `absolutePath` as a string. Work with `File` objects!

```
File myFile = new File("post_tran.tbl").getAbsoluteFile();
File outputDir = new File(myFile.getParent(), "test");
if ( ! outputDir.exists() ) {
  outputDir.mkdirs();
}
File outputFile = new File(outputDir, "final.tbl");
// Operate on outputFile ...
```

Comment: It is taking wrong value in myFile. Its taking any random path. Why is it so?

Comment: Because `new File("post_tran.tbl")` will assume the file is in the *current* working directory at the time the program runs. Just like when you'd use `./post_tran.tbl` on a command line. If that's not what you want you'll have to specify the absolute path, either as a single string argument (using the correct file separator character) or as a chain of `File`s, like `new File( new File( new File( "c:" ), "my input dir" ), "post_tran.tbl" );`.